# Chrome and FF Display "margin-top" Differently

Tags: css, google-maps, google-chrome, browser

my google map  works fine in firefox and IE. but when loading by chrome, the map will be in the top . and it also seem like all code functionality works fine
i found the 
margin-top:-400px;   /*map position*/
    margin-left:-400px;  /*map position*/
work find in firefox,but work in chrome is too top
part of my code as follows:

```
<style>
BODY {
 font-family : Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; 
 color: #000000; 
 font-size : 13px ; 
 background-color:#8ba4d9; 
 }
 #map_canvas {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;

box-shadow: 1px 5px 5px #666;

position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;

margin-top:-400px;   /*map position*/
margin-left:-400px;  /*map position*/
}
</style>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
</script>
 <div id="map_canvas" align="center" style="width:65%; height:90% ; position: relative;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script

google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geomap']});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

```
function drawMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'Popularity'],
    ['Germany', 200],
    ['United States', 300],
    ['Brazil', 400],
    ['Canada', 500],
    ['France', 600],
    ['RU', 700]
  ]);

  var options = {};
  options['dataMode'] = 'regions';

  var container = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
  var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(container);
  geomap.draw(data, options);
```

};

AND

have u added https://www.google.com/jsapi'> to your page (this script is important)

Comment: hi aashi, i have try you code ,but it's shown different in fifrefox and chrome

Comment: @aashi: question is about Google Maps JavaScript API, see `new google.maps.Map()`, you are answering with solution with Google Visualization API.